# I dont know how to install a game for linux

Tags: software-installation, games, urban-terror

Yeah, im new at Ubuntu and i still dont know how to install games on it. I downloaded Urban Terror and Champions of Regnum. Urban Terror is .zip file but for Champions of Regnum says ROInstall_64. I was trying like 3 hours to install them but it seems impossibele. Please hep me!

Comment: So which one are you trying to install and could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

For Champions of Regnum, you should just right click the file, click properties, permissions, and then checkmark "allow executing file as program". Then close out of that and then double click the file. Should install fine.

Check it out: https://www.championsofregnum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27971

Comment: Now i only need to find explanations for Urban Terror.

Comment: @PrOfSeS: try any of this links: https://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=install+linux+Urban+Terror 
Let us know what worked.